# glm c++ outputs difference value on each loop

Tags: c++, glm-math

I have the following code in c++

```
for(int count = 0; count < 10; count++)
        {

                glm::vec4 vec(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
                glm::mat4 trans;
                trans = glm::translate(trans, glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

                vec = trans * vec;
                cout << "x: "<< vec.x <<" y: "<< vec.y <<" z: "<< vec.z << endl;
        }
```

The loop prints the following

```
x: 5.60519e-45 y: 0 z: 3.92364e-44
x: 8.40779e-45 y: 0 z: 5.88545e-44
x: 1.12104e-44 y: 0 z: 7.84727e-44
x: 1.4013e-44 y: 0 z: 9.80909e-44
x: 1.68156e-44 y: 0 z: 1.17709e-43
x: 1.96182e-44 y: 0 z: 1.37327e-43
x: 2.24208e-44 y: 0 z: 1.56945e-43
x: 2.52234e-44 y: 0 z: 1.76564e-43
x: 2.8026e-44 y: 0 z: 1.96182e-43
x: 3.08286e-44 y: 0 z: 2.158e-43
```

Why do the value keep changing with every loop. Shouldn't the result be the same ?

Comment: at some point glm changed the behavior of the default constructor. are you sure it initializes the matrix? I have a sneaking suspicion it doesnt which would explain the problem. (ISTR this behavior is controlled by a define)

Comment: `trans` is not initialized. `glm::mat4 trans;` ->  `glm::mat4 trans(1.0f);`

Comment: That was it . Thanks